# jQuery - Best way to find elements by a custom CSS key in their "style" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a page where some elements have a fake CSS property called "key" like this :

```
<div style="color:red;key:settings.color;background-color:violet;key:settings.bkgColor;"> 
</div>
```

I want to find these elements by their key. I have come up with this :

```
function getElsByCssKey(){
    var foundEls = [];
    var style;
    $( "*" ).each(function(){
        style = $(this).attr("style");
        if(typeof style !== "undefined" && style.indexOf("key") !=- 1){
            foundEls.push(this);
        }
    })
    return foundEls;
}
```

I guess there are faster/better ways to do that ?

Comment: What is the reason behind in using custom key? Why can't it be a CSS class?

Comment: because we built our template rendering system with values coming from an object (key/value). now it turns out we must know from which key a value comes from. it would be a very very long work to add classes to each element. instead, I routed all the gets for value in a function, which can add the key to it. but because the value was a css value, it is returned in the element's css. so the only way to put the key in there is by using a fake css property

Comment: @IrishGeek82 this answer uses jquery.css which (correct me if I am wrong) doesn't work with inline style props

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do, but I do not know which elements Have custom keys and which ones don't. So, I'd have to select all $("*") and then use your regexp. Which is a better solution than the .each and .indexOf I used before, but $("[style*='key:value']") seems to be even better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$("[style*='key']").each(function(){

 });
```

This will return all elements which contains the style attribute `key`

**Edit**

```
 $("[style*='key:listColor']").each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("style"));    
  });
```

Comment: Nice, but how to return the key value then ?

Comment: very nice. One last thing, how to get elements with a specific key ?
For example only elements with "key:listColor;". I know I could add a check in the .each but is it doable with the query directly ?

Comment: use $("[style*='key:listColor']"). for that

Comment: The selector does work but not the alert. This is because .css doesn't look into inline style (at list not invalid ones) so it alerts ("undefined")

Answer (score 1):

You can go like this:

```
$("[style*='key']").each(function(){
    foundEls.push($(this));
});
```

The document is here :http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this i think

```
var key = $( this ).css( "key" );
```

usually we can get any css property using this

```
var color= $( this ).css( "color" );
```

so that may work out for you.